# Why is receive called a method?

Tags: scala, akka

The [Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/actors.html) call Actor's receive as a method. But as per the API it is a abstract type member rather than an abstract method. Any reason why receive is termed as a method?

Comment: could you be more specific? receive from which class? maybe a link to the akka docs you are referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, docs could be improved a bit.

If you take a look into the [Actor trait](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Actor.scala#L483), you will notice that `receive` is indeed a method. The `Actor.Receive` in its signature is the type member you are referring to, defined in the [Actor object](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Actor.scala#L340).

So, `receive` is an abstract method that every Actor needs to implement. Its type is partial function; you can easily tell because it takes a bunch of case statements, e.g.

```
def receive = {
  case "test" => log.info("received test")
  case _      => log.info("received unknown message")
}
```

Each case statement takes `Any` and returns `Unit`, so the actual type of the partial function is `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`. For clarity and simplicity, Akka guys decided to create a placeholder for that particular type, they called it `Receive` and they put it in the Actor companion object.

Small digression: a lot of folks are not really happy with messages being of type `Any` and Akka guys have promised to introduce typed messages; not sure if they delivered it yet in the latest release though.

Comment: Regarding the digression about typed messages, the [Akka Typed](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/typed.html) feature is available, but still experimental, in recent releases.